# Anaconda Jupyter Notebook blank page when open

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have already download and installed the Anaconda. However, I have a blank page when I open the Jupyter Notebook. I dont know what happen.

Jupyter Notebook: 6.4.5

MacOs: 12.2.1

Comment: Changing the browser solved this problem for me once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Google Chrome and solved my problem by reading the official Jupyter Notebook page in the section "Jupyter fails to start".

https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html

In my case, one of my Chrome extensions was messing with Jupyter, I disabled them all and reactivated them one by one until I found which one was messing up.